# How to create geometric shapes in html

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image]

I just want to create above image with the use of HTML and CSS. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Show what are u tried so far [code] ?

Comment: did you tried it ? share your code

Comment: Your better off using SVG

Comment: i am not having any source code... i just want to create a design like this. even i didn't understand why all putting negative for my question. i asked like a question only.

Comment: who all r put negative please check the answer :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex design pattern - overlapping transparent shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587509/complex-design-pattern-overlapping-transparent-shapes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to accomplish what you're looking for, but it can be accomplished using SVG, z-Index, Opacity and Clipping.

Run the code and I think you'll see it matches.  The colors might not be exact but they're close enough to show you what goes where.  You can also separate the Styles from the HTML and put in a CSS file, but it was just faster for me to build it this way.

I hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#col1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
#col2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
#col3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -2;
}
#col3a {
    opacity: 0.90;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
#col4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -3;
}
#col4a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 4;
}
#col5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -4;
}
#col6 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -5;
}
#col7 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed; 
    display: block;
    z-index: -6;
}
#col8 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: -7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col1">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="200" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="400" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="600" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="800" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="300" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="500" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="700" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col3">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="400" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="600" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="800" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col3a">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="400" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="600" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="800" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col4">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="300" cy="500" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="300" cy="700" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col4a">
<svg width="1000" height="1000" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip1">
      <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100" />
      <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip1)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip2">
      <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
      <circle cx="200" cy="400" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip2)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip3">
      <circle cx="200" cy="400" r="100" />
      <circle cx="200" cy="600" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="300" cy="500" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip3)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip4">
      <circle cx="200" cy="600" r="100" />
      <circle cx="200" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="300" cy="700" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip4)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip5">
      <circle cx="200" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="300" cy="900" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip5)" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col5">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="400" cy="0" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="600" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="800" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col3a">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="600" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="800" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col6">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="500" cy="100" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="500" cy="700" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col4a">
<svg width="1000" height="1000" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip6">
      <circle cx="400" cy="0" r="100" />
      <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip6)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip7">
      <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="100" />
      <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip7)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip8">
      <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="100" />
      <circle cx="400" cy="600" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip8)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip9">
      <circle cx="400" cy="600" r="100" />
      <circle cx="400" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="700" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip9)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip10">
      <circle cx="400" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="900" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip10)" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col7">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="600" cy="0" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="400" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="600" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="800" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col3a">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="400" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="600" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="600" cy="800" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col8">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="700" cy="100" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="700" cy="300" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="700" cy="500" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
  <circle cx="700" cy="700" r="100" fill="#aba31a" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col4a">
<svg width="1000" height="1000" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip11">
      <circle cx="600" cy="0" r="100" />
      <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="700" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip11)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip12">
      <circle cx="600" cy="200" r="100" />
      <circle cx="600" cy="400" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="700" cy="300" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip12)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip13">
      <circle cx="600" cy="400" r="100" />
      <circle cx="600" cy="600" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="700" cy="500" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip13)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip14">
      <circle cx="600" cy="600" r="100" />
      <circle cx="600" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="700" cy="700" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip14)" />
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip15">
      <circle cx="600" cy="800" r="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="700" cy="900" r="100" fill="#ffffff" clip-path="url(#clip15)" />
</svg>
</div>  
<div id="col3a">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="800" cy="200" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="800" cy="400" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="800" cy="600" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
  <circle cx="800" cy="800" r="100" fill="#326e78" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="col1">
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="900" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="900" cy="300" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="900" cy="500" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="900" cy="700" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
  <circle cx="900" cy="900" r="100" fill="#ffffff" />
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ShanuShaji I enjoyed the challenge of figuring it out, despite the fact that the Illuminati feel it to be inappropriate for the exchange.  Enjoy!

Comment: the people who don't know this, they put negative flag :P